# Google_ServiceException: Error calling POST

Tags: php, google-drive-realtime-api

I need help.
Trying to send file to the google drive from localhost.
1. I downloaded sample project and substitute my credentials
2. Then I got:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart: (403) Access Not Configured'`

Google says nothing, but perhaps you have any idea, what is wrong?
Code

```
<?php
session_start();
$url = 'http://localhost/api/';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('1027833231791.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('iriHG1HKCCYLphkSatrpOn_p');
$client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $_SESSION['accessToken'] = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    header('location:'.$url);exit;
} elseif (!isset($_SESSION['accessToken'])) {
    $client->authenticate();
}
$files= array();
$dir = dir('files');
while ($file = $dir->read()) {
   if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
       $files[] = $file;
    }
}
$dir->close();
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);
    $service = new Google_DriveService($client);
    $file = new Google_DriveFile();
    foreach ($files as $file_name) {
    $file_path = 'files/'.$file_name;
    $mime_type = 'text/plain; charset=us-ascii';
    $file->setTitle($file_name);
    $file->setDescription('This is a '.$mime_type.' document');
    $file->setMimeType($mime_type);
    $service->files->insert(
        $file,
        array(
            'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
            'mimeType' => $mime_type
        )
    );
  }

    header('location:'.$url);exit;
}
```

Comment: I got it...
Try this solution http://ben.akrin.com/?p=2080 , it was really helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have "Drive API" turned on (not "Drive SDK" ;) Unless you want that one too). I made this mistake also.